# jQuery/PHP ajaxForm getting JSON encoded results

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajaxform

I got this code for the Form:

**jQuery**

```
 $('#form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function () {
        bar.width(0);
    },
    uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {

        var percentCompleted = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentCompleted)
        bar.text(percentCompleted)
        console.log(percentCompleted);
        ///The Console logs properly.
    },

    complete:
    //------------------------------------
    //THIS IS WHERE LIES PROBLEM IS
    //------------------------------------
    function (xhr) {
        //How do you convert the xhr to JSON?

        //I tried :
        var out = JSON.parse(xhr)
        // and :
        var out2 = $.parseJSON(xhr)

        console.log('Completed1: ' + out);
        console.log('Completed2: ' + out2);
    },
    error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr)
        console.debug(xhr);
        console.log("Desc: " + desc + "\nErr:" + err);
    }

});
```

---

**The PHP is like:**

[image]

[image]

`$OutCollection` is an Associative `Array()`

---

**Firebug Console says:**
[image]

Cant figure out what's really Wrong.

Any help is highly appreciated.

---

**PHP output / response in firebug**

[image]

---

**Console.log(xhr) prints**

[image]

Comment: Could you give us an example output from the PHP script?

Comment: Maybe `xhr` is already an object. Do a `console.log(xhr)` and see what you get.

Comment: Please see the result of the  `console.log(xhr)`... thx again

Answer (score 3):

It seems that xhf is a `XMLHttpRequest` object so the `responseText` property will have your json.

```
function (xhr) {
    //How do you convert the xhr to JSON?

    //I tried :
    var out = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
    // and :
    var out2 = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)

    console.log('Completed1: ', out);
    console.log('Completed2: ', out2);
},
```

Answer (score 2):

### Solved the mystery:

Using the hint from **@Musa** in the comment that suggested to try the `console.log(xhr)`,

I came up with this.

```
var out=$.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);

     $.each(out,function(i,v){
    //then:
    console.log(out[i]) //to access each piece of the information.

    });
```

However,

Somehow, both parameters of the `$.each()` are returning the `key` of the `key=value` pair. I somehow thought the `i` should be the `index` and the `v`, value of the `$.each` loop. So  that we could do something like: `v[i]`. using `i` as an index to access the values stored in the `v` Array of values.

Even though, it works *hackingly* however.

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont have that `;` after that `variable` declaration like:

```
 var out= JSON.parse(xhr);
 var out2= $.parseJSON(xhr);
```

Comment: Even with a single variable like: `var out= JSON.parse(xhr);` only, I still get the error...

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is **HTTP header**

We need to make the browser think the receiving data is json and then you don't need to parse the returning string to json.

Just need to add this before you echo the json encoded string:

**`header("Content-type: application/json");`**